# How to make my wordpress site Multi-region

Tags: plugins

I have a website that I want to make **multi-region**. In this case I want some pages of the website to be different on each region, also the **menu** should be different.

For example. I want a website that will be available in Colombia, Mexico and Costa Rica.

I want that when you enter the URL: `mysite.com/co/` it shows you the Colombian version of the homepage, the menu for the colombian site and even somepages can be the same, let's say for example: `mysite.com/mx/FAQs` should display the same page as `mysite.com/co/FAQs`.

I don't want to duplicate pages because It'd make the administration a true hell when we have 4, 5 other regions to add.

What plugin do you recommend for this? I tried Polylang to emulate this behavior, but I'm having problems trying to re-use pages instead of duplicating them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible or suggested to do it without duplicated pages, but I know that with the WPML plugin you can keep in sync duplicated versions.

Answer (score 0):

I do the exact same as what you require using PolyLang on my e-commerce store.
The store is mainly used by foreigners, but is based in Thailand. So the website uses the default language of English, but has the option to switch to Thai. If the user switches to Thai, a Thai version of the page is display instead with different content. (I swayed away from these *auto page translators* as Google Translate for the Thai language is not very accurate for any sentence that contains more than 4 or 5 words!)

Depending on the language selected, both the product pages, additional pages, the home page and the menu can be fully customised with a different look, if that is what you desire.

Also, if some pages will be the same on both versions of the site, then no country (Or region) extension is required.

**For example:**

> www.mysite.com/co/some-page-1

and

> www.mysite.com/mx/some-page-2

But...like you previously stated, there still is no way to reuse pages so the **some-page-1** will display whichever countries content. Another page has to be created for each language's different content unfortunately. This is a bit of a pain I must agree.

The above two pages would have different content suitable for each location, however a *Frequently Asked Questions* page could be placed like this:

www.mysite.com/faq

No *co* or *mx* location extension needed. Just a simple page that can be added to the menu. The link on the menu would direct to the same page. This defeats having to create a FAQ page for 50+ regions if they are all going to be duplicates of one-another.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like **WPML, Polylang**, etc. for this. And it is not like creating duplicate pages. You don't need to manage different pages.

You can translate manually or automatically.

If you are using manual translation, then you can translate word by word or paragraph by paragraph. And you will have a separate place for that where you can input translation for the content. And this is not like managing different pages.

> example.com/test - Original version
>
> example.com/en/test - New version

For every language your URL will be different but that doesn't mean you have to manage duplicate pages.

Also, you can use JSON for translating without using a plugin. But it would be difficult to manage. This is the [github](https://github.com/Irrelon/jquery-lang-js/) link.
Thank you